# create json dynamic jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to create another JSON file, through this API , but I can not , the result is coming out just as [ ]

I need to access this api (https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/time/+time) for each value of ARRAY TIMES , receive the results individually and take only the KEYS I need to create a new ARRAY / JSON

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var result = [];

var times = new Array("sport-clube-balao", "verdao-f-c-s-p", "kibeb-s-fc", "maria-fumaca-futebol-clube", "skolusa-fc", "fc-chikungunya", "furia-verde-1988-f-c", "deixaa-queto-f-c", "peixeraum", "espinoza-fc", "s-e-palestra-parente", "ca7fc", "lebucchi-fc", "impactos-fc", "tricolor-futebol-amigos", "augustinho-s-fs", "os-cara-de-egua", "porcos-locos-fc", "toniolotricolor-fc", "massa-clube", "made-china", "pipoca-jacare", "deprimeira-f-c", "rocca-uryntians", "hu100-f-c", "gabrukas-tln", "zaca-clube", "poderoso-rorinthians", "kbca-futebol-clube", "666fc", "e-c-corinthi-ns", "mpupo110-fc");

    $.each(times , function(key, val) { 
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/time/' + val,
        format: 'json',
        error: function () {
            alert('Ixi parça! Ocorreu um erro ao exibir as parciais, aguarde alguns segundos');
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            result.push({
                    nome_time: data.time.nome,
                    nome_cartola: data.time.cartola,
                    escudo: data.time.url_escudo_png
            }); 
            console.log(result);
        }
        });
    });
});
```

if i put 
        console.log(result);
outsite the success of the ajax
i just receive [] on the console

I would like the following result

```
times:[0]
{name:name, escudo:escudo, ...},
[1]
{name:name, escudo:escudo, ...},
```

Comment: @4castle i need an object like this
[0] {
        name: name
         ....
}
[1] {
        name: name
         ....
}

Comment: It looks like your code is working - https://jsfiddle.net/v61a47L5/

Comment: @Steve no. i want to return all data at once, if you look into console, my code return 1 object on every step of the loop, just like [object], and [object][object], i just need the final one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning `[]` because all of the $.ajax are running in parallel.

Using `$.when.apply()` and passing all of the requests in, essentially awaits all requests, and then runs `console.log(result)`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var result = [];

  var times = new Array("sport-clube-balao", "verdao-f-c-s-p", "kibeb-s-fc", "maria-fumaca-futebol-clube", "skolusa-fc", "fc-chikungunya", "furia-verde-1988-f-c", "deixaa-queto-f-c", "peixeraum", "espinoza-fc", "s-e-palestra-parente", "ca7fc", "lebucchi-fc", "impactos-fc", "tricolor-futebol-amigos", "augustinho-s-fs", "os-cara-de-egua", "porcos-locos-fc", "toniolotricolor-fc", "massa-clube", "made-china", "pipoca-jacare", "deprimeira-f-c", "rocca-uryntians", "hu100-f-c", "gabrukas-tln", "zaca-clube", "poderoso-rorinthians", "kbca-futebol-clube", "666fc", "e-c-corinthi-ns", "mpupo110-fc");

  var requests = [];

  $.each(times, function(key, val) {
    requests.push($.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/time/' + val,
      format: 'json',
      error: function() {
        alert('Ixi parça! Ocorreu um erro ao exibir as parciais, aguarde alguns segundos');
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        result.push({
          nome_time: data.time.nome,
          nome_cartola: data.time.cartola,
          escudo: data.time.url_escudo_png
        });

      }
    }));
  });
  $.when.apply(null, requests).done(function() {
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
var x = {times : result}
JSON.stringify(x);
```

after `$.each(times , function(key, val){}`

Comment: just add, but, don´t work.
if i put 
    console.log(result);
outsite the success of the ajax
i just receive [] on the console